# How to make user gestures follow a postMessage event

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, gesture, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I have a web page (non public) with an iframe, where the relation between outer page and iframe is [same-site cross-origin](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/). To send events from the outer page to the inner page, I'm using [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) calls.

The events do things such as start playback on a webAudio object in the inner page –  which requires a user gesture in order to not be considered "auto play" which gets blocked by the browser.

Sending a postMessage event to start playback works fine as long as both pages (outer and inner) have the same document.domain property, but [document.domain is deprecated and not a future-proof solution here.](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/immutable-document-domain/) so I cannot rely on it.

So when sending a cross-origin same-site postMessage call to start audio playback in Chrome – without document.domain and without first clicking in the iframe in order to make an "interaction" with it – the response will be "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.".

The problem seems to be that user gestures are not following along with the postMessage event.

From what I can gather on the web, postMessage *should* still be a working method for making such calls between same-site, cross-origin pages, so I don't understand why it's not working. There are a few bug reports that touch upon this issue ([such as this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161068)), but to my understanding, the issue should be solved by now.

I have tried the Message Channel API, which still uses postMessage, and did not get any different results.

Is there a solution to this?
On developer.chrome.com they mention sending the "Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?0" header as a "last resort", but is this really the only solution here?